# How to set master feature branch as default in Teamcity 9.1

Tags: git, teamcity, gitlab

I'm using teamcity 9.1 against gitlab, and trying to get the gitlab / teamcity service hook working. Gitlab can correctly trigger builds, but the problem is that it's coming up in teamcity as a separate feature branch called 'master', distinct from the default branch which is also called 'master'.

I've tried setting the default branch to be `master` as well as `refs/heads/master`, and I've tried adding in `+:refs/heads/(master)` to the feature branch specification, but the fundamental issues is that triggering a build setting `branch=master` (as the gitlab hook does) does something different to triggering a build with `branch=default`.

I then end up with lots of projects that look like this:

[image]

This is somewhat annoying, as gitlab-triggered builds don't show up in the artifact shortcuts like `.lastFinished`, because they reference the `default` branch and it doesn't seem to think that `master` triggered from gitlab is the default.

Is this a bug in teamcity, or am I configuring it wrong?

Comment: did you manage to fix this?